# find specific information inside array

Tags: php

I have an url like that and i must extrac specific information

```
....localhost/test/shop/index.php/Products/Description/apple-15-inch-macbook-pro-laptop/products_id-11
....www.mydomain.com/shop/index.php/Products/Description/apple-15-inch-macbook-pro-laptop/products_id-11
..../www.mydomain.com/index.php/Products/Description/apple-15-inch-macbook-pro-laptop/products_id-11
```

apple-15-inch-macbook-pro-laptop must extracted
products_id-11 must be also 11 id of the product

Like you see the position $`key` is different in function the url.

I make that to start, but it do nwork in all case.
How to resolve that ?

```
private function explodeUrl(): ?array
{
  return explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
private function getProductId(): ?int
{
  $products = $this->explodeUrl();


  foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 7){
      $products_id = str_replace('products_id-', '', $value);
    }
  }

  return $products_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your product id always comes at the last position you can do something like this:

```
// explode using '-'
$params = explode('-', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// printing product id
echo $params[count($params)-1]; // 11
```

Comment: `echo end($params);` or `echo array_pop($params);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = $this->explodeUrl();
// `array_pop` will give you last item of `$products` array
$value = array_pop($products);
echo str_replace('products_id-', '', $value);

// and also this last item will be removed from `$products`
// so you can use `array_pop` again and get second part of your string:
$productCode = array_pop($products);
echo $productCode;
```